# jackson deserialize SparseArray

Tags: android, json, parsing

I'm using jackson 2.4 to parse an object from a json string. My object is some thing like that:

```
{
.....
SparseArray<Integer> classesIds;
....
}
```

And the json is like that:

```
.......
"classesIds":
{"mValues":[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16],
"mKeys":[0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15],
"mSize":16}
..........
```

And when I used `mapper.readValue(json, type);` it throws a JsonMappingException saying **unknown property**; given I parsed it using Gson but Gson parsed the integres to double which gives cast exception when I access this classesIds field.

So, how can I parse SparseArray in jackson.

Comment: How do you expect the `mapper` to map that Json object to a `SparseArray`? They don't really look the same...

Comment: SparseArray has these mKeys, mValues, mSize fields ; I have already parsed it in this format using Gson library. If you think it is invalid, so what is the correct format?

Comment: Well no I don't have answer - then I would probably have provided that as well, don't you think? :-)
I'm thinking that because the `SparseArray` doesn't have any setters and gettings, you won't be able to parse it. You might have to go and extend the `SparseArray` with your own implementation with actual setters and getters.